# How to center an image that is higher than the container?

Tags: css, image, containers, center

I have searched some solutions related with my case, but all the questions are not totally the same with my case.

The image must be set to `width:100%` and `height:auto` for the container(300x150). I don't know what the uploading image width will be in my case, so **I guess I can't use background-image for the solution**.

This is not working:

```
#image-container {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.img {
 width: 300px;
 height: auto;
 position: absolute; /*this is for my working frame, can't change*/
}
```

Demo link:
http://jsfiddle.net/bardirian/zPg5m/

**---update--**

It works with the background-image idea from btlr.com
see demo updated here:
http://jsfiddle.net/bardirian/zPg5m/7/

When I try to add this to my html I found the other problem is a jquery element needs the image to be imported from the html, so I am still looking for a better css solution but not background-image.

Comment: Are you open to a JavaScript solution? Can you use jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

what about something like this

```
<div id="image" class="clearfix blog-image" 
    style="background:   url('http://i.imgur.com/5d8taEj.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    ">


</div><br />
```

**background-size: contain;**   - this will work with the background, I've just checked it on your demo (try to reduce the size of your div)

Comment: surely, you can have some JS  to set the background-image of your container div in code

Comment: Just seen your " I can't use background-image for the solution."  Sorry, will try to think of  some other solution ...

Comment: Thank you, yes I can't go with background-image.

Comment: You can use background with background-size: contain (vs cover) - try it

<div id="image" 
     style="background:   url('http://i.imgur.com/5d8taEj.jpg') center center no-repeat;   background-size: contain; ">


http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-css3-background-20110215/#the-background-size

Comment: alright, I'm so appreciated that you really thought about it. I'll try if it works for my case, back later. Thanks again!

Comment: My friend, it works! just need to add loop in php.
THANK YOU!
see demo here http://jsfiddle.net/bardirian/zPg5m/7/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38142/discussion-between-bard-and-btlr-com)